# Efficient threading scheme

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupt

I'm writing a java GUI that performs certain operations through the serial port. Since I don't want it to block while waiting for a response I figured having a thread do it was a better way, but now I'm faced with two options and I don't know which would be more efficient:

- Case 1: Create a single thread for each asynchronous task.
- Case 2: Keep a single thread sleeping and have it perform different tasks by changing an atomic integer's value and then interrupting it.

None of these operations will be processor intensive, but I still wonder if it's wise to keep a thread in memory permanently.

Comment: There is a Case 3: have a third thread waiting, not sleeping. You need to use wait()/notify(). The best solution depends on the number of simultaneous tasks than eventually can be processed at the same time. But assuming you serial port is not really fast, with 2 threads is enough.

Comment: 'I still wonder if its wise to keep a thread on memory permanently' - if there were no threads in memory, you could not do anything at all in your app because there would be no execution.

Comment: In theory there will be no simultaneous tasks since the communication is established for a very short period of time. Still, I want to know if there's a best practice or if these are just different yet valid options. @Martin James what I meant by that, was a thread other than the main one.

Comment: What kind of operations?  Synchronous request/response or something more complex?

Comment: @rodkarom - you cannot just keep the serial port open, then?

Comment: It's mainly request/response, I suppose I could keep it open while the application is being used, since what I'm connecting can only be controlled with the application I'm writing.

Comment: @rodkarom - then do so.  Continually opening/closing COM ports, or continually doing anything, really, when you can avoid it, is just poking the OS with a stick. Eventually, it will turn on you and bite back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a single threaded ExecutorService like

```
private final ExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

service.submit(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
       // task to perform here.
   }
});
```

You may want a different thread for reading and writing to the serial device.

Comment: Are tasks queued or something like that?

Comment: Yes tasks will be queued.And will be executed in the order you have submitted them if you use `SingleThreadedPool`.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html), I guess this is all what you need.

As suggested by Peter you can create `ExecutorService` using  [newSingleThreadExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor%28%29) and use it to process your tasks.

Comment: There is a risk that the serial device is access by more than one thread or in an unexpected order than one thread at a time if you create multiple  threads.